# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion on OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: vb.net, oledbdataadapter

I am seeing the following error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Historydata()
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        con.Open()

    End If

    Dim dataadapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from approvedmasterlist where = '" & txtid.Text & "'", con)

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data to datatable
    dataadapter.Fill(dt)

    'offer data in data table into datagridview
    DataGridView1.DataSource = (dt)

    'close connection
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Can anyone explain the error and why it is happening?

Comment: Do not post images of code. Just copy and paste the code. And about the error. How do you declare the _con_ variable? Please [edit] your question

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. What is `con` declared as? As a side note I would also use SQL parameters as you're currently open to SQL injection and further syntax issues.